# Access Google Drive REST without google sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a lightweight node.js module that needs to pull from google drive. They have a REST/HTTPS interface but AFAICT it's only accessible via their SDK. I want to use REST/HTTPS so I don't have to use an SDK. Is this possible for file download? For file find (file:list e.g. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list)?

Comment: By "*not use the SDK*", do you mean the [libraries](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_install_the_client_library)? AFAIK, you could make use of REST/HTTPS calls directly, so long as you'd be able to supply the corresponding credentials and parameters in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think it's only accessible using an SDK. The link you posted clearly shows the URL endpoint, lists the optional parameters and gives the format of the JSON response.

If you click "Try it now" and open your browser console, you will see the http request and response which you can mirror in your app.

The only thing you also need to consider is that before making a REST request to Google, you must obtain an Access Token and set it in an `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx` header, or provide it as a query parameter as `&access_token=xxxxxxxxx`